# how to find unique word in text file and then store unique words in text file using powershell

Tags: powershell, text-files, unique, cpu-word

I am using PowerShell. Here I want to remove duplicate words from the text file and then store the unique words in the text file. What I do is here.

```
$A = $( foreach ($line in Get-Content C:\Test1\File1.txt) {
    $line.tolower().split(" ")
  }) | Sort-Object | Get-Unique
$A | export-csv "somefile.csv"
```

Here is my [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10lVyynystbYACYBxn1Od-tHtyiJdQsiE/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: So what is the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PowerShell can use a dotnet type called a hashset which is perfect for doing exactly this, and at the figurative speed of light too!

First we read the file into memory in PowerShell and assign it to a variable called `$lines`.

Next, we split into just the unique `$words`.

Finally, we create a hashset which will only allow unique words or items.

```
$lines = get-content "C:\Users\Stephen\OneDrive\Documents\quotes.txt"
[string[]]$words = $lines.Split()
$uniqueWords = [System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]]::new($words)
```

Here's some info on how this works, we're using [the hashset constructor which accepts an input value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Collections_Generic_HashSet_1__ctor_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable__0__).

**But its FAST!**

It is amazingly fast to use a hashset too! I measured the performance on a reasonably sized file of **10MB** of text from samplefile.com with a number of famous quotes and other info.

```
Method           TotalMs
------           -------
Get-Unique    21484.4956
Using Hashset  1840.7407
```

Get hashset is dramatically faster.  It's an order of magnitude faster in the worst case, and I've seen it be two orders of magnitude or more before.

Comment: is i have to set-content also to write it on the text file? @FoxDeploy

Comment: `$uniqueWords` has all of the content, you just set it out to a file by adding this to the end `Set-Content $uniqueWords -Path 'C:\temp\uniqueWords.txt'`

Comment: i Have 161Mb file to do. is there any fast way other than that. Apreciate your explanation to make this query work fast.

Comment: Check my edit, but using the hashset approach is the fastest approach you can use in PowerShell.  Remember to vote up if useful.

Answer (score 1):

Or simply as one-liner

```
(Get-Content 'C:\Test1\File1.txt' -Raw) -split '\W' | Sort-Object -Unique | Set-Content -Path 'C:\Test1\File2.txt'
```

<sup>`\W` is regex for a Non-Word character like space, comma, etc.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The main issue with your example was that you weren't processing the returned array from the split function:

```
Get-Content hello.txt | ForEach-Object { $wrds=$_.Split(" "); foreach ($i in $wrds) {  Write-Output $i } } | Sort-Object | Get-Unique
```

Split each line into the array wrds and then loop on the contents to write the output before performing the sort and processing the duplication.